# How to usefully calculate using "dark state polariton" framework?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-optics

I'm interested in looking at calculations related to storage of light in atomic systems.

[This](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.84.5094) paper discusses how these types of systems can act as "memories" by generating "dark state polaritons."

I can loosely follow the mathematics up until a certain step. 
First, since the optical-Bloch & Maxwell-Schodinger equations are coupled, they perform some perturbative expansion to reduce it to a simpler PDE:

[image]

Then they introduce a substitution which simplifies the differential equation:
[image]

Then they look at the new differential equation that describes this substitution:

[image]

Which they say has a solution of the form:
[image]

So how exactly do I use this "polariton operator" to observe how specific light states get stored?

For example, if I have a single photon state and no initial coherence, how do I calculate what happens to the coherence (if I adiabatically switch off the $\Omega(t)$, and then turn it on again).

From the equations that I've been given, I see that I can plug in for $\hat{E} |1\rangle$ and maybe plug in for $\sigma_{bc}$? I see this $\sigma_{bc}$ is probably a Heizenberg operator, but isn't this just a single value? I don't see how it's an /operator/. How do I choose its initial value?

Even if I successfully plug in values and get an answer for $\Psi$, how does this answer tell me how the E-field is changing in time? or how the coherence is changing over time? I can see that there is a E-field contribution and a coherence contribution to $\Psi$ (and that by changing $\theta(t)$, I can change the scaling of each contribution), but how does this tell me how my system as a whole will behave with some particular initial conditions?

Any type of simple math or examples showing how to actually work this this object would be greatly appreciated. (For example, what does the input and output look like, when doing the "switching" procedure for an input of a fock-state vs a coherent state?)

Comment: I am reading through the paper, and while I understand the appearance of the polariton operator as the integrating-out of the excited state $|a\rangle$, I don't understand the physical content of the equation (8): $\hat{\sigma_{bc}} (z,t) = - g \hat{E}(z,t)/\Omega(t)$. The dipole operator acts on a different Hilbert space (e.g. atomic internal state) than the electric field operator (photon state). Is this related to your question/confusion about $\sigma_{bc}$ being single-valued?

Comment: Ah, I think that is because the operators are in the Heisenberg picture so that the $e^{\pm i\hat{H}t/\hbar}$ on the left and right of the operators $\sigma_{bc} = |b\rangle\langle c|$ and such would make the equation consistent. If it were in the Schrodinger picture it would be a non-sensical statement.

Comment: @AmIAStudent, yes I think the differences in Hilbert space between operators is confusing.  |b⟩⟨c| if it were a matrix, would just have a single nonzero element in the basis of the atomic states. So then it could be expressed just as a "variable" instead of a "matrix". I was thinking that maybe the "hat"-notation is signaling that |b⟩⟨c| is actually put in terms of the fock-state basis of the E-field. Maybe I was thinking it was a singular value but it's also a matrix in the fock-state basis (and each atomic density matrix term has its e-field-fock-state matrix $H_{atom}\otimes H_{E-field}$.